# Multiple Fragments using the same CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursorloader

I am having a problem with an application that I am trying to write. The application opens 2 fragments in a viewpager which are configured to use the same cursorloader configured to use contentprovider which access's an sqllite database. The first fragment has a "category" spinner which is populated by the cursorloader and the second fragment has a "category" spinner and also an "item" spinner as the "items" are grouped by category, both spinners are populated using the same cursorloader.

From the main screen I have icons to edit/insert a "category" or edit/insert an "item". If I click to edit a "category" it loads the first fragment and selects the "category" in the spinner. If I click to edit an "item" it loads the second fragment and selects the "category" and "item" based on the item selected.

The first time I click to edit an item the second fragment loads correctly and both the "category" and "item" spinner are displayed correctly, however if I go back to the starting screen and click to edit another "item" the second fragment loads but no data is displayed. After debugging I can see that the second fragment is created and the cursorloader is initialised (initloader) and onCreateLoader is called then the first fragment is created and the cursorloader is initialised (initloader), onCreateLoader is called followed by onLoadFinished. onLoadFinished never gets called for the second fragment and hence no data is displayed. If I swipe to the first fragment and back to the second fragment it finishes the original call.

**Is this an issue that you cannot use the same CursorLoader simultaneously?**

I have tried using the `getLoaderManager().getLoader("data")` to determine whether to use initloader or restartloader but each fragment seems to have its own loader and `getLoaderManager().getLoader("data")` always returns null. I have also tried setting up a view of the table and accessing the table via the cursorloader on one fragment and the view via the cursorloader on a different fragment.

I hope you get an idea of the problem I am facing and can either suggest a fix or even a different way of using the same data in two fragments. The reason I decided to use cursorloader was due to how it integrates with spinners and updates the data held in the controls by itself. If need be, I can post some code.

**Update**
After further investigation the onStart() and onResume() methods of the second fragment are not being called after being created the second time, although when I swipe to the first fragment and then back to the second they are then called.